# Vba Excel Code does not read a third worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working with two workbooks, both with different sheets. The code is writen for the Workbook called "Rober.xslm" and in the following macro I open another workbook ("Formato permisos.xlsm") and read values in some sheets to work with them in my original workbook. Firstly I managed to read the values from the sheet "Requisitos contenedor + ATI" in the workbook "Formato permisos.xlsm" and work with then in my sheet "Seleccion_ECs" from "Rober.xlsm".

The problem comes when I select, or activate, or open the sheet "ECs full" from the workbook "Rober.xlsm". I don't understand why this statement:
Set shECF=wbDest.Worksheets("ECs full")
returns Nothing if I also have this one:
Set shrelacion=wbDest.Worksheets("Relación ciclo y fechas")
and it works with it! The name ECs full is well written. It's a normal sheet, not a chartsheet.

```
Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(sFileName)

Debug.Print (wbSource.Name) '"Formato permisos.xlsm"

If Err.Number <> 0 Then Debug.Print ("Error number en Libro gráficas: " & Err.Number)

If Err.Number = 0 Then Debug.Print ("No ha habido error en libro gráficas")

Set Requisitos = wbSource.Worksheets("Requisitos Contenedor + ATI")

Set QvsE = Workbooks.Open(sFileName) 'wbSource.Charts("Curva - QvsE")

Set wbDest = ThisWorkbook 'Workbooks("Rober.xlsm")

Debug.Print (wbDest.Name) '"Rober.xlsm"

If Err.Number <> 0 Then Debug.Print ("Error number en Libro Rober: " & Err.Number)

Set shEC = wbDest.Worksheets("Seleccion_ECs")

If Err.Number <> 0 Then Debug.Print ("Error number en hoja Seleccion_ECs: " & Err.Number)

im fechaActual As Variant, fechaEOC As Date

Dim shECF As Worksheets, rangoECF As Range

Dim nFilasECF As Double, nColumECF As Double, años As Double

Set shECF = wbDest.Worksheets("ECs full")

'wbDest.Sheets("ECs_full").Activate --These are some thigs I tried

'wbDest.Sheets("ECs_full").Select


If Err.Number <> 0 Then Debug.Print ("Error al seleccionar hoja ECs full: " & Err.Number)

MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Path & vbNewLine & ThisWorkbook.Name 'Archivo Rober

Set rangoECF = Sheets("ECs full").UsedRange

    nFilasECF = rangoECF.Rows.Count

    nColumECF = rangoECF.Columns.Count

Set shrelacion = wbDest.Worksheets("Relación ciclo y fechas")

For g = 1 To nColumECF

    If shECF.Cells(1, g) = "último ciclo de operación" Then

        C = shECF.Cells(1, g).Column 'Don't manage to get this value since I can't read the sheet "ECs full"

    End If

Next g
```

Comment: Check the name of the sheet "ECs full" to make sure it doesn't have a trailing space at the end (i.e. "ECs full ").

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to see this

```
Dim shECF As Worksheet
```

(Not Worksheet**s**)